# Path alias causes "cannot find module" ts(2307) error in one .vue file but not another .vue file?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to use path aliases (`~/utils/assets`) in my Vue 3 SFC (single file component) file. I am using the [Volar VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar), and the issue occurs even after enabling "[Takeover mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#takeover-mode)" with the Volar plugin.

1. As you can see in the screenshot below, the `Home.vue` file is able to reference `import { zipFromImages } from "~/utils/assets";` without any issues. However the `Preview.vue` file—which is located in the same directory as `Home.vue`—is NOT, and throws the ts(2307) error: `Cannot find module '~/utils/assets' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`.
2. When I select the `Preview.vue` file (a Vue SFC `.vue` file), the bottom of VS Code shows "No tsconfig". When I select `Home.vue` file, it properly shows "tsconfig.json" there and links to my `tsconfig.json` file as expected.

[image: VS Code errors]

Has anyone else faced these issues and found a solution?

### What I've tried

- [x] Followed [official Vue + TypeScript instructions](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#overview)
- [x] Using latest VS Code & plugin versions
- [x] Using latest NPM packages

### Configuration

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "module": "esnext",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/ui/*"
            ],
            "~/*": [
                "./src/ui/*"
            ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./node_modules/@figma"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx",
        "src/**/*.vue"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { viteSingleFile } from "vite-plugin-singlefile";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const isDev = mode === "development";
  return {
    plugins: [vue(), viteSingleFile()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui"),
        "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui"),
      },
    },
    build: {
      outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/ui"), // The output directory
      minify: !isDev,
      sourcemap: true,
      watch: isDev
        ? {
            exclude: ["dist", "node_modules"],
          }
        : null,
      target: "esnext",
      assetsInlineLimit: 100000000,
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 100000000,
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      brotliSize: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          manualChunks: () => "everything.js",
        },
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
      },
    },
  };
});
```

### Version information

VS Code & VS Code plugins

- VS Code 1.65.2
- Vue Language Features (Volar) v0.33.2
- TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar) v0.33.2

NPM Packages

- Vite 2.8.6
- Vue 3.2.6
- Typescript 4.6.2
- @vue/compiler-sfc 3.2.6
- @vitejs/plugin-vue 2.2.4
- vite-plugin-singlefile 0.7.1

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/894

Comment: Appears to be solved by renaming `Home.vue` and `Preview.vue` to `HomePage.vue` and `PreviewPage.vue`, which is in line with Vue 2's [component naming conventions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Multi-word-component-names-essential)